# What happens exactly when we backbite someone?

Tags: sin, deeds, backbiting

I am confused about the losing good deeds and gaining sins rule when backbiting someone.

For example:

(1) If Person A is backbiting Person B, does Person B get every single good deed of Person A and Person A get every single sin of Person B?

(2) If the above is true: If Person A repents to Allah and asks for forgiveness sincerely and Allah forgives Person A, will the good deeds that Person B got from Person A transfer back to Person A? Or did Person A lose the good deeds completely even after being forgiven by Allah?

(3) If Allah forgives Person A for backbiting, will Person A still be punished?

(4) If a muslim backbites a non-muslim and vice versa, does the rule of good deeds and sins being taken and given still apply?

(5) What is the punishments for backbiting? And how can we make sure that we don't backbite so we don't get punished?

Comment: Ask one focused question per post.

Answer (score 0):

If you backbite about a muslim,on the day of judgment they will take some of your good deeds if you have backbitten multiple people all of them are going to take some of your good deeds if your good deeds ran out but there are still people you have backbitten then you take their sins. There are different opinions if you should apologize to the victim or not. You can search it up on Youtube or on Google. But a Sheikh said you don't need to apologize to kafir. However you should repent even if you only have backbitten one person or two because backbiting is a major sin.